# gnome-terminal Breaks After Changing the Default Size at Startup

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, gnome-terminal

I tried [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/72176/linux-set-default-terminal-size-and-screen-position), but it broke my Gnome Terminal, with this error message:

`There was a problem with the command for this terminal`
`Text was empty (or contained only whitespace)`

I tried reinstalling it and uninstalling/reinstalling it to no avail.  Anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?  I really need my terminal ;-)

EDIT - I should clarify...  Before the terminal broke, I could spawn a new terminal with the command:

`gnome-terminal --geometry 120x30`

It broke after I placed the same command but with an "=" in the config settings and saved it.  It just so happens that I had a working terminal open when all this happened and it is still functioning fine, indicating that the terminal works OK, but the launcher is corrupted.

Comment: that exact command works for me on the commandline to spawn a new gnome-terminal of the specified size and position.  haven't tried adding that to the startup program list, but i'm on 10.04 so your problem may be 9.10 specific.  does it work for you if you execute it on the commandline?

Comment: See my EDIT above...  I could spawn the terminal too from the command line.

Comment: @quack - I actually run both karmic and lucid, as a dual boot system for testing purposes.  I mainly run 10.04.  The funny thing is, 10.04 has the option in the GUI to set this exact parameter.  I wonder if I could transfer the gnome-terminal from lucid to karmic?  Would that work?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "broken".  you mean *any* gnome-terminal won't start now?  or just ones that use the `--geometry=...` argument?

Comment: Broken as in the terminal wont start and is accompanied by the error in my original question.  The window actually opens, but there is no prompt and typing in the window is unresponsive.  But I fixed it anyway, so the point is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by un-checking the box  by an option, under `Profiles > Title and Command`, called "Run as a custom command instead of my shell."  This was checked when I altered the custom option under `System > Preferences > Preferred Applications`, System tab.  I still haven't figured out how to make the custom configuration stick, but I at least found a way to fix my terminal when I experiment with tweaking it.

**EDIT** - Also, the reason the original error said `Text was empty (or contained only whitespace)` was because when the checkbox was checked, the command was missing (under `Profiles > Title and Command`).  So, thinking I could simply add the command and actually use the "Run as a custom command instead of my shell" I entered `gnome-terminal --geometry 120x30` and clicked close.  Then when I opened the terminal, it started to freak out and it appeared like the terminal was being launched repeatedly, very quickly.  @quack, if you happen to try this as well, maybe you could explain this odd behavior?

**What fixed the problem and serves as this answer:**

I edited the /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop file with the Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=120x30 line and this finally gave me what I wanted...

Comment: wait.  you checked the "run as custom command" setting and entered `gnome-terminal` as the command???  you made it recursive.  it broke because every time gnome-terminal started, it tried to run the command gnome-terminal, which tried to run the command gnome-terminal, which .... should have resulted in a stack overflow of gnome-terminals.  ish.  that's the theory, anyway.  not something i'll be testing out, tyvm.  :)

Comment: I know, I know...  Very rookie mistake!  So I finally edited the `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop` file with the `Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=120x30` line and this finally gave me what I wanted...  Thanks for drilling me appropriately for doing something stupid ;--)  I know realize why you wouldn't want to test this on your system.

Comment: you said you followed the procedure from [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/72176/linux-set-default-terminal-size-and-screen-position), but that's not really what you did, was it? nowhere in the question or the comments had you mentioned that you set "run as custom command" that way.  next time be explicit about what you've done, what you've tried and what's happening.

Comment: Actually it was exactly what I did...  it caused the original error (the one in my original question).  Only in my answer did I mention the `Profiles > Title and Command` set of steps and the fact that the recursive behavior was an additional problem.  I explored the behavior as I progressed through asking the question and, subsequently, answering my own question.