# Ubuntu equivalent of OSX Terminal.app "Window Group" for saving size, position, number of terminals?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal, window

Just like the title... I am looking for an Ubuntu alternative to OSX's Window Group. On OSX, I can open a few terminals, resize them, position them perfectly, and then save the configuration. Every time I use Ubuntu, I have to open multiple terminals by hand and resize/position by hand... is there a similar function in Ubuntu I can take advantage of?!

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: See my answers [here](http://superuser.com/a/619990/151431) and [here](http://superuser.com/a/610048/151431), will one of those options do for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script or launcher to setup multible terminal tabs in different locations](http://superuser.com/questions/610001/script-or-launcher-to-setup-multible-terminal-tabs-in-different-locations)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Terminator offers all the features you require. Technically, it only opens a single terminal window, but you can have as many panes, split any way you like. Once you get a setup you like, it is simple to save your "profile" for later use.

Terminator Home: http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html
Easy Ubuntu Install: sudo apt-get install terminator