# windows 10 ubuntu change default window size

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've tried ccsm as in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/72176/linux-set-default-terminal-size-and-screen-position), but it crashes immediately with GtkWarning: could not open display...AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_screen'

I've also tried xterm and gnome-terminal but also get display related errors.

Is it possible to set a default window size for the Ubuntu terminal in Windows 10?

Comment: Ubuntu terminal uses conhost.exe. To change Window size right click on the Windows tittle ang choose the properties.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: No, you may answer you own question. You'll get a badge :)